# How To Intercept Low-Level Windows File Rename API

Tags: .net, qt, file-io, windows-10, file-rename

Is there a way on Windows 10 to (a) **programmatically detect the low-level call for renaming a file**, and (b) **identify which process is doing it**, whether it's done by Microsoft .NET, GCC, Qt/C++, or other C language?

Comment: That requires a [file-system minifilter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers), like what [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) does. For example, a rename via `MoveFileEx` calls the system service [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567096) to set the `FileRenameInformation`. Then the I/O Manager calls the file system device stack with an [`IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549366).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From eryksun:

That requires a [file-system minifilter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers), like what [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) does. For example, a rename via `MoveFileEx` calls the system service [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567096) to set the `FileRenameInformation`. Then the I/O Manager calls the file system device stack with an [`IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-set-information).